# Allowing subclasses to be added to a list with Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I do not understand why the compiler does not allow this:

```
Callable callable = null;
List<Future<BaseClass<? extends AnotherClass>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<BaseClass<? extends AnotherClass>>>();

class BaseClass<T extends AnotherClass> {
   ...
}


class Subclass extends BaseClass<ConcreteType> {
    ...
}

class ConcreteType extends AnotherClass {
    ...
}

futures.add(new FutureTask<Subclass>(callable));
```

Why is this not allowed?

Comment: Should it not be: `futures = new ArrayList<Future<BaseClass<? extends AnotherClass>>>();` (you forgot the `Future`)? And you also forgot a closing `>`.

Comment: You didn't yet correct the missing closing `>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
List<Future<? extends BaseClass<? extends AnotherClass>>> futures
```